# grails findAll with conditions or executeQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy, subquery

I have been spending some time on this. My problem involves bringing back domain objects with certain criteria and conditions:

I have a large set of bikes. There is a possibility of having multiple bikes with similar wheel size. For example I can have 5 bikes:

```
owner_id | bike | wheel | price | active | toolset | forLance
_________|______|_______|_______|________|_________|__________
15459    |liner |    12 |  100  |     Y  |   null  |   H       
15459    |larker|    15 |  150  |     Y  |   null  |   H      
15459    |jefro |    21 |  225  |     Y  |   null  |   H      
15459    |raz   |    21 |  230  |     Y  |   null  |   L      
15459    |jynx  |    21 |  295  |     Y  |   null  |   P
```

My query below retrieves the all the bikes with non-duplicate wheel size and lowest price.

MySQL query:

```
select * from bike b 
where b.owner_id = 15459 
and not exists( select * from bike 
where wheels = b.wheels AND price < b.price 
and owner_id = b.owner_id)  and b.active = 'Y';
```

The result will give me the rows with the bikes : **liner, larker, and jefro**.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in grails//groovy? ( Get **liner, larker, and jefro** into a list of domain objects)

I have tried using a structure like:

```
def bikes = Bike.executeQuery(...)
or
def bike = Bike.findAll(...)
```

But I cannot seem to execute a query with a similar structure to the MySQL script I made.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MySQL you are using subqueries to retrieve the data. AFAIK this is not possible with GORM. What you could do is writing it in [Hibernate Query Language (HQL)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#hql)

Lets assume your Domain Class is called Bike.

```
Bike.findAll("from Bike as b where b.active = 'Y' and b.owner = :owner and b.id in elements(select b1.id from Bike where b1.owner = :owner and b1.active = 'Y' and b1.price < b.price)", ['owner':owner])
```